# How to display my image in ImageView (CUSTOM CAMERA)

Tags: android, camera

I created a custom camera app that saves the image in SD.
I have another activity that involves an ImageView.
I want to display the photo taken from camera in ImageView.
How should I do that?

```
    public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "CUSTOMCAM";
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private SensorManager sensorManager = null;
private int orientation;
private ExifInterface exif;
private int deviceHeight;
private Button ibRetake;
private Button ibUse;
private Button ibCapture;
private FrameLayout flBtnContainer;
private File sdRoot;
private String dir;
private String fileName;
private ImageView rotatingImage;
private int degrees = -1;
private Uri imageUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    // Setting all the path for the image
    sdRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    dir = "/DCIM/Camera/";

    // Getting all the needed elements from the layout
    rotatingImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ibRetake = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ibRetake);
    ibUse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ibUse);
    ibCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ibCapture);
    flBtnContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.flBtnContainer);

    // Getting the sensor service.
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    // Selecting the resolution of the Android device so we can create a
    // proportional preview
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    deviceHeight = display.getHeight();

    // Add a listener to the Capture button
    ibCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }
    });

    // Add a listener to the Retake button
    ibRetake.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Deleting the image from the SD card/
            File discardedPhoto = new File(sdRoot, dir + fileName);
            discardedPhoto.delete();

            // Restart the camera preview.
            mCamera.startPreview();

            // Reorganize the buttons on the screen
            flBtnContainer.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
            ibRetake.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
            ibUse.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
        }
    });

    // Add a listener to the Use button
    ibUse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Everything is saved so we can quit the app.
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, PicturePreview.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
}

private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        // Replacing the button after a photho was taken.
        flBtnContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ibRetake.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ibUse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // File name of the image that we just took.
        fileName = "IMG_" + new           SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date()).toString() + ".jpg";

        // Creating the directory where to save the image. Sadly in older
        // version of Android we can not get the Media catalog name
        File mkDir = new File(sdRoot, dir);
        mkDir.mkdirs();

        // Main file where to save the data that we recive from the camera
        File pictureFile = new File(sdRoot, dir + fileName);

        try {
            FileOutputStream purge = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            purge.write(data);
            purge.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        // Adding Exif data for the orientation. For some strange reason the
        // ExifInterface class takes a string instead of a file.
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface("/sdcard/" + dir + fileName);
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, "" + orientation);
            exif.saveAttributes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //SendBroadcasts let's us instantly update the SD card with our image
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
    }


};

private void createCamera() {
    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    Setting the right parameters in the camera
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    mCamera.setParameters(params);

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

    // Calculating the width of the preview so it is proportional.
    float widthFloat = (float) (deviceHeight) * 4 / 3;
    int width = Math.round(widthFloat);

    // Resizing the LinearLayout so we can make a proportional preview. This
    // approach is not 100% perfect because on devices with a really small
    // screen the the image will still be distorted - there is place for
    // improvment.
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, deviceHeight);
    preview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    // Adding the camera preview after the FrameLayout and before the button
    // as a separated element.
    preview.addView(mPreview, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Test if there is a camera on the device and if the SD card is
    // mounted.
    if (!checkCameraHardware(this)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NoCamera.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    } else if (!checkSDCard()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NoSDCard.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

    // Creating the camera
    createCamera();

    // Register this class as a listener for the accelerometer sensor
    ////sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // release the camera immediately on pause event
    releaseCamera();

    // removing the inserted view - so when we come back to the app we
    // won't have the views on top of each other.
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.removeViewAt(0);
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

/** Check if this device has a camera */
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean checkSDCard() {
    boolean state = false;

    String sd = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(sd)) {
        state = true;
    }

    return state;
}

/**
 * A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object.
 */
public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        // attempt to get a Camera instance
        c = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }

    // returns null if camera is unavailable
    return c;
}

/**
 * Putting in place a listener so we can get the sensor data only when
 * something changes.
 */
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            RotateAnimation animation = null;
            if (event.values[0] < 4 && event.values[0] > -4) {
                if (event.values[1] > 0 && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                    // UP
                    orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90;
                    animation = getRotateAnimation(270);
                    degrees = 270;
                } else if (event.values[1] < 0 && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                    // UP SIDE DOWN
                    orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270;
                    animation = getRotateAnimation(90);
                    degrees = 90;
                }
            } else if (event.values[1] < 4 && event.values[1] > -4) {
                if (event.values[0] > 0 && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL) {
                    // LEFT
                    orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
                    animation = getRotateAnimation(0);
                    degrees = 0;
                } else if (event.values[0] < 0 && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                    // RIGHT
                    orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180;
                    animation = getRotateAnimation(180);
                    degrees = 180;
                }
            }
            if (animation != null) {
                rotatingImage.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        }

    }
}

/**
 * Calculating the degrees needed to rotate the image imposed on the button
 * so it is always facing the user in the right direction
 *
 * @param toDegrees
 * @return
 */
private RotateAnimation getRotateAnimation(float toDegrees) {
    float compensation = 0;

    if (Math.abs(degrees - toDegrees) > 180) {
        compensation = 360;
    }

    // When the device is being held on the left side (default position for
    // a camera) we need to add, not subtract from the toDegrees.
    if (toDegrees == 0) {
        compensation = -compensation;
    }

    // Creating the animation and the RELATIVE_TO_SELF means that he image
    // will rotate on it center instead of a corner.
    RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(degrees, toDegrees - compensation, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    // Adding the time needed to rotate the image
    animation.setDuration(250);

    // Set the animation to stop after reaching the desired position. With
    // out this it would return to the original state.
    animation.setFillAfter(true);

    return animation;
}

/**
 * STUFF THAT WE DON'T NEED BUT MUST BE HEAR FOR THE COMPILER TO BE HAPPY.
 */
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_cam, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

this is the code 
and then I have a second activity that I need to call the image taken

Comment: post the code you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the saved image path in string. Then pass it to other activity with Bundle.

eg.
In your camera activity
under your ibUse.setOnClickListener. Like this;

```
ibUse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Everything is saved so we can quit the app.
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, PicturePreview.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("ImagePath", path);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

});
```

In your preview activity under onCreate method

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String path = bundle.getString("ImagePath");

ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
File imgFile = new  File(path);

if(imgFile.exists()){
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Comment: Where should I put the first Intent?

Comment: Thank you very much.. One last question I hope..  "Cannot resolve symbol path" What to do?

Comment: Can you paste the line throwing err

Comment: I just need to alt+Enter path to make it String or something.. Its not declared anywhere in my code. But what exactly should I do?

Comment: Error:(118, 47) error: cannot find symbol variable path
(Im not a man...)

Comment: Ok I set everything right but I get no image in Image.. 
I mean it takes me to my PicturePreview.java but I cant see the image.

Comment: If error still occurs can you paste 2 classes whole. Sorry if i offended you, man was just a general term.